# How to formulate Regular expression for given example

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not very well versed with regular expressions. I've had to use them, maybe once every few years, and that was mostly for course work. Anyways, the following question should be a fairly straight forward question/answer for anyone familiar with regular expressions.

I need to ensure that the text entered into a field follows the following format:

```
x y z
```

or

```
x,y,z
```

or

```
x y z / <same pattern can repeat for almost unlimited length>
```

or

```
x,y,z / <...> // Spaces after the comma are ok
```

where x, y and z can only be integers. The patterns cannot be intermixed, so you cannot have

```
x, y, z / x y z / ...
```

I've tried the following

```
([1-9] [1-9] [1-9])
```

to get the x y z part, but I don't know how to include the '/' nor the ','

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can use

```
Regex r = new Regex("^([0-9]+([ ,]|, )[0-9]+(\\2)[0-9]+)( [/] ([0-9]+(\\2)[0-9]+(\\2)[0-9]+)+)*$");

var x1 = r.IsMatch("1,2 3");         // false
var x2 = r.IsMatch("1 3 2 / 1 2 3"); // true
var x3 = r.IsMatch("1,3,2");         // true
var x4 = r.IsMatch("1 3 2 / 1");     // false

Console.WriteLine((x1 == false) ? "Correct" : "Error");
Console.WriteLine((x2 == true) ? "Correct" : "Error");
Console.WriteLine((x3 == true) ? "Correct" : "Error");
Console.WriteLine((x4 == false) ? "Correct" : "Error");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Spliting in smaller pieces

```
[0-9]+  matches any number, even 0. If it can't start with 0
        you will have to change it
[ ,]    the separator allows a space or a comma
\\2     matches the same thing the second group matched (space or comma)
```

The second big parenthesis matches or not more iterations of this sequence if started by `/`.

If all separator needs to be exactly the same, replace them by `\\2` (just don't replace the first, that is what it is going to match for the group 2).

Comment: I tested what you suggested using this [REGex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/), it didn't seem to work for the case with commas. Perhaps I missed something.

However, I tried your suggestion through DevExpress' XtraGrid TextEditor MaskEditor (a mouthful I know). But reading through documentation it says they do not support back references, which I'm assuming the `\\2` is supposed to do. So unless there's a way to strictly enforce a space or a comma (but not both) , I'll just have to settle for a mixed mode.

Comment: If it's not supported then I'm afraid to manage the mix with something else. I've tested this expression on a console project.

Comment: I figured out how to incorporate your suggestion into what I needed to do. Except, `r.IsMatch("1 3 2 / 1")` returns true. I only want it to return true if and only if it's written out with the 3 coordinates for each "section" or whatever you want to call it; `1 2 3 / 1 2 3`. Etc. 

I'll keep playing around with it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It was matching `1 2 3 / 1` because I missed start (`^`) and end (`$`). I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 5):

Try to break your regular expression down into pieces. Then try to combine them.

For example, an integer like `1024` is a sequence of one ore more digits, i.e. `[0-9]+`. Etc.

*Grammar:*

```
digit     ::= [0-9]
space     ::= [ ]
slash     ::= [/]
comma     ::= [,]

integer   ::= digit+
separator ::= space | comma
group     ::= integer separator integer separator integer
group-sep ::= space slash space
groups    ::= group ( group-sep group )*
```

*Regex:*

```
([0-9]+[ ,][0-9]+[ ,][0-9]+)([ ][/][ ][0-9]+[ ,][0-9]+[ ,][0-9]+)*
```

Comment: +1. Just FYI, this will allow the mixing of commas and spaces within a group of integers. Not sure if that's an issue, but I read the OP's requirements as being one or the other.

Comment: Matches `1,2 3` which I'm not sure if it's valid for the OP.

Comment: It cannot mix between commas and spaces, so it would have to be:
1 2 3 OR 1,2,3 and this is ok too 1, 2, 3

Comment: @Agent: See my answer for a bit of explanation on `\\N`